# How to send an array through socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am storing all users in an Array and i want to send that array to all clients throught socket.io. I have this code

```
var players = new Array();

io.on('connection',function(socket){
var player = {
    id: socket.id,
    serverid: 0,
    x: randomInt(100,400),
    y: randomInt(100,400)
};
players[socket.id] =  player;
```

Thats how i store it and then i emit it to clients

```
io.emit('new_player',players);
```

but all i am getting is an empty array, but emiting single player work.

whole code

```
var players = new Array();

io.on('connection',function(socket){
var player = {
    id: socket.id,
    serverid: 0,
    x: randomInt(100,400),
y: randomInt(100,400)
};
players[socket.id] =  player;
io.emit('new_player',JSON.stringify(players));
socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('dced');
});
```

});

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't empty ? Try with `players.push(player)` instead of `players[socket.id] = player` (which would make sense if it was an object literal).

Comment: im sure the array is filled with data, tried consoleloging it and there are for sure data

Comment: Did serializing (server side) then deserializing (client side) change anything ?

Comment: no it didn't change anything still empty array. I tried it with .push and it works, but that defeats that i wanted to have that array's keys named by socket.id

Comment: Then use an object literal instead `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionnary instead of an `Array` for what your doing:

```
var players = {}; // Dictionnary instead of an array

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var player = {
    id: socket.id,
    serverid: 0,
    x: randomInt(100,400),
    y: randomInt(100,400)
  };

  players[socket.id] =  player;
  io.emit('new_player', players); // Send the dictionnary

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('dced');
  });
});
```